# How does this URL has something before www?

Tags: image, dns, icann

I've never seen that before! How's does that works? I know ICANN now allows custom domain names, but it's before **www**! I've tried to add another www before **welcome** and it returned 404.

[image: welcome.www]

Comment: Please copy the actual url here - or we will consider your spoofed URL to be potential spam.

Comment: u mean www1.domain.com or such?

Comment: It's ironic that the OP's image link is at i.stack.imgur.com, considering the question.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

www is not something special. There is no difference for server between www or www1 or welcome. There are websites without www at all.
Actually www is subdomain and you can create two different websites: one on www and another without.

Comment: This is exactly what I didn't know. I thought you couldn't have a world-wide web server without the 'first' domain being necessarily 'www'. But after reading the wiki article it turns out that the parent domain is the one to the right, so everything makes sense now.

Answer (score 2):

[RFC 1035](https://www.rfc-editor.org/rfc/rfc1035) defines the grammar below.  Also, you may want to see [this wikipedia article](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Domain_name).

```
<domain> ::= <subdomain> | " "

<subdomain> ::= <label> | <subdomain> "." <label>

<label> ::= <letter> [ [ <ldh-str> ] <let-dig> ]

<ldh-str> ::= <let-dig-hyp> | <let-dig-hyp> <ldh-str>

<let-dig-hyp> ::= <let-dig> | "-"

<let-dig> ::= <letter> | <digit>

<letter> ::= any one of the 52 alphabetic characters A through Z in
upper case and a through z in lower case

<digit> ::= any one of the ten digits 0 through 9

Note that while upper and lower case letters are allowed in domain
names, no significance is attached to the case.  That is, two names with
the same spelling but different case are to be treated as if identical.

The labels must follow the rules for ARPANET host names.  They must
start with a letter, end with a letter or digit, and have as interior
characters only letters, digits, and hyphen.  There are also some
restrictions on the length.  Labels must be 63 characters or less.

For example, the following strings identify hosts in the Internet:

A.ISI.EDU XX.LCS.MIT.EDU SRI-NIC.ARPA
```

Answer (score 1):

People can put whatever they like in subdomains, then tell the server to "treat `example.com.au` the same as `www.example.com.au`"

therefore you could have a "real" URL of, eg:

```
www.abc.www.example.com
```

then tell the server to allow:

```
abc.www.example.com
```

This *may* be what you're seeing...

Comment: If it were I'd be able to access www.welcome.www.be[...], I guess.

Comment: I said in my question that it didn't work, but as Wikipedia's article taught me, 'www' is not strictly necessary nor needs to be first. (=

Comment: you'll only have access to the "www" version if the server has it switched on... most do by default, but they may have not done so just to be funky with their domain...

Answer (score 1):

It's a 4th level subdomain, where www of www.example.com is a 3rd level as example is a sub of .com.

So, subdomains can do down 127 levels, such that my.desktop.www.example.com would be an valid URL with in thise case the www, in the middle.

Look at something like a traceRT anything, you might see something like dsl123.sfv.la.example.com (or whatever), point is, there are many cases of multi level subdomains, with or without the WWW - Another example might be mail.phx.example.com, a mail server for the phoenix office of a company.